# Error Could not find or load main class when adding "extends" to the top class

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am having a bad time trying to figure out how to solve a simple error in the view, but that none of the answers to the same reported error is helping me resolving my issue.

I am using cygwin in a Windows 10 on a 64 bit machine.

I am trying to compile an example from www.processing.org but it is not working so I created a basic "hello processing" code that shows the error I am trying to solve.

When I run this code:

```
import processing.core.*;
import processing.data.*;
import processing.event.*;
import processing.opengl.*;

public class HelloProcessing  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Processing");
    }
}
```

with these commands:

```
javac -cp core.jar HelloProcessing.java
java HelloProcessing
```

I can see the "Hello, Processing" message displayed.

But if I change the "HelloProcessing class"code to:

```
import processing.core.*;
import processing.data.*;
import processing.event.*;
import processing.opengl.*;

public class HelloProcessing extends PApplet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, Processing");
    }
}
```

With exactly the same commands, I get the

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class HelloProcessing" message.
```

Why is this?

Comment: do you add the `pApplet` class to the classpath?  BTW, is pApplet and Applet, if so it should run in a browser

Comment: What java version are you using -- looks like latest version of PApplet will only work with Java 8: http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/index.html?processing/core/PApplet.html